# Where is the dependency to the jar file being set?

Tags: grails, junit

Sorry Grails noob here.
I am looking at a project which has some references to JUnit in its test code.  I am trying to figure out how JUnit is being added to the classpath.  I go to the BuildConfig.groovy file and I see no explicit reference to JUnit.

The dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    test "org.spockframework:spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0"

    runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4'
    compile 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.2'
    compile 'spy:spymemcached:2.8.9'
    compile "org.grails:grails-webflow:$grailsVersion"
    compile 'org.infinispan:infinispan-core:5.1.0.CR2'
}
```

The plugin dependencies are:

```
plugins {

    test(":spock:0.7") {
        exclude "spock-grails-support"
    }

    runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    compile ":geoip:0.2"
    compile ':cache:1.0.0'
    compile ":quartz:1.0-RC9"
    //compile ":quartz-monitor:0.3-RC2"
    compile ":grails-melody:1.45"

    compile ':webflow:2.0.0', {
        exclude 'grails-webflow'
      }
}
```

So any ideas on what could be bringing in the Junit jar or how I'd find out what it is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

JUnit is part of the grails packaging by default. You should be able to find junit jar in `lib` of grails bundle which you would have downloaded from grails.org in

`GRAILS_HOME\lib\junit\junit\jars`

You can also verify how it is added to the project by running `grails dependency-report` on the project and looking for `junit` jar in test scope.

The latest version of junit shipped with Grails 2.2.3 is `junit-4.10`.